# How to install and run oracle 12c in oracle linux 6.5?

Tags: oracle-database, oracle-linux

I was trying to install oracle linux 6.5 from [this](http://technology.amis.nl/2013/06/29/how-to-create-a-virtual-box-vm-with-oracle-enterprise-linux-inside-a-dummy-guide/#prettyPhoto) link. I downloaded the OracleLinux-R6-U5-Server-x86_64-dvd . Now while installing I didn't get any GUI as the link said I would get after test/skip menu. But I installed the server without GUI any way in the vbox. I have ubuntu-14.04 as host. But now when in terminal I can't connect the internet from the guest.I have selected bridged adapter in the settings.

The main purpose of installing oracle was to use and practice the oracle database 12c1. I don't actually need internet as long as I can run sql commands in oracle server.

As there is no GUI , I am really frustrated now.
So if someone could tell me step by step command of how to
1) connect to the internet 
2) login to the oracle 12c server so that I can run sql commands.Non-GUI or GUI mode.

Comment: OL images don't contain Oracle Database, you'd need to install that separately. You'd probably be better off taking a prebuilt dev VM with the database & tools already installed (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html), e.g. the Database App Development VM.

Answer (score 1):

To install Oracle Linux 6.5 **with** GUI you have to make changes in the following setup page while installing linux.

[image: configure software]

The screenshot is in german, but don't be confused :)

Activate the checkbox at the bottom "Configure now" and click "Next".

Then you have to go to "Desktops" and choose the prefered GUI.

Click on "Next" to proceed the installation process.